# Angular error with HTML file

Tags: html, angular

This is my file

```
<div class='panel panel-primary'>
  <div class='panel-heading'>
    Product List
  </div>
  <div class='panel-body'>
      <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-2'>Filter by:</div>
          <div class='col-md-4'>
              <input type='text' />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-md-6'>
              <h3>Filtered by: </h3>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class='table-responsive'>
          <table class='table'
              <th>
                  <tr>
                      <th>
                          <button class='btn btn-primary'
                              Show Image
                          </button>
                      </th>
                      <th>Product</th>
                      <th>Code</th>
                      <th>Available</th>
                      <th>Price</th>
                      <th>5 Star Rating</th>
                  </tr>
                </th>
              <tbody>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting these errors

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "button". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. 
Unexpected closing tag "th". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.

Comment: You're missing a > on the button tag. Not sure if that's just a copy paste error or the actual error. Double check your code.

Comment: And you're using <th> as the first child in the table, that is supposed to be <thead>.

Answer (score 1):

Two missing closing tag found in the HTML you need to fix them

`<table class='table'` here make it `<table class='table'>`

another one is

`<button class='btn btn-primary'` make it `<button class='btn btn-primary'>`

Answer (score 0):

You missed closing > in **button tag** and also in **table tag.**

```
  <button class='btn btn-primary'>
              Show Image
  </button>


<table class='table'>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>
                      <button class='btn btn-primary'>
                          Show Image
                      </button>
                  </th>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Code</th>
                  <th>Available</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>5 Star Rating</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```